# How to redirect URLs with blank space in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I use this URL that contains %20 I don't get expected response.

```
localhost/worldsindia/company-search.php?company=Orissa%20Electrical%20Industries
```

This is with .htaccess

```
localhost/worldsindia/search/Orissa%20Electrical%20Industries
```

It is my PHP code, When I use .htaccess I get wrong response but when I use normal URL I get the expected response.

```
if(isset($_GET['company'])){
    $ss = $_GET['company'];    

}
echo $ss;
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $0.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)  company-search.php?company=$1 [NC,L]
```

Output:-

1. With .htaccess is Orissa.
2. With normal URL(localhost/worldsindia/company-search.php?company=Orissa%20Electrical%20Industries) Orissa Electrical Industries

Comment: %20 is a space character.

Comment: urlencode and urldecode  functions will be of help, I believe

Comment: what about get request not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RegEx is the expression that helps .htaccess to read your URL and achieve what you want.**

Look at your Regex Last line in .htaccess :
`([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` It means accepting ONLY alphabet And digits. **NOT SPACE CHARACTER**

Why it cause problem when it comes to %20 ?
**Because %20 means space in URL**, You are searching *"Orissa Electrical Industries"*.

So you should accept space character too, **How** ?

With **`\s`**, it means Space character in **RegEx**.

### It will be like this :

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)  company-search.php?company=$1 [NC,L]
```

PS: [You can check and play with Regex in this RegExr](https://regexr.com/4ijpt)

Comment: i have litle doubt if there is . in end for ex-"Orissa Electrical Industries." the same rewrite rule i use or it change

Comment: @Shivam If you want to accept . too you can add it after \s you can read about Regex and you can edit your regex how you want it

Comment: ok i used like this [A-Za-z0-9-\s.]+) but output is Orissa Electrical Industries.php